# VB Listbox change value

Tags: vb.net

How can i change a value in a VB Listbox?

Like this it doesn't work:

```
listbox.selectedItem = "Newvalue"
```

THX for help

Comment: Do you want to change the item that is currently selected in the `ListBox`? Or do you want to change the text/name that is displayed for the current selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listbox.List(listbox.ListIndex) = "NewValue"

Answer (score 1):

**Adding items to listbox:**

```
ListBox1.Items.Add("AA")
ListBox1.Items.Add("BB")
ListBox1.Items.Add("CC")
ListBox1.Items.Add("DD")
```

**now select anyone 1 option in the listbox:**

[image: image1]

**Add this code in your button click**

ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "newvalue"

[image: image2]

the selected option/value "CC" is changed to "newvalue"